# Sitemap in MVC3 without using any third party tool

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvcsitemapprovider

I am trying to create a sitemap in Asp.Net MVC3.

Is there any control given by Microsoft to create a sitemap in MVC3 using Razor view Engine?

If not then, is it possible in MVC3 to to create a sitemap, without using any third party tool like Nuget MvcSiteMapProvider Package?

Comment: I have researched a lot on this question but could not find anything. I have only found some examples using the Nuget Package for this.  Please tell me that whether this case is possible or not. Do I need to depend on this third party tool only?

Answer (score 0):

You can always roll your own, which is what I do, but here are some existing implementations:

https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider

http://keyvan.io/sitemap-action-result-for-asp-net-mvc

I use something similar to the second implementation and it has worked very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Before I started contributing to [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider), I searched for an answer myself and came to the conclusion the answer is **no**. Microsoft didn't provide any built-in way to build a sitemap, search engine sitemaps files, or SiteMapPath controls in ASP.NET MVC, all of which MvcSiteMapProvider does.